# Concatenating branches(of different dimensions) of googlenet on Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

is there any way I can concatenate branches of different dimensions of a small inception(googlenet)?

For example, at a 32 x 32 x 3 image (torch.Size([1, 3, 32, 32])), it will pass through an inception module with the following branches:

- a convolution with (32 channels, 1 x 1 filters)
- another convolution with (32 channels, 3 x3 filters)
- merge (concatenate along the channel dimension)

[Inception Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beru0.png)

The issue however is that the torch sizes as a result of the two convolutions are different.
(32 channels, 1 x 1 filters) -> [1, 32, 30, 30]
(32 channels, 3 x3 filters) -> [1, 32, 28, 28]

How can I concatenate the two branches?
Should I add padding? I tried ZeroPad2d. It’s not working.

For your reference:

```
class Inception(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_channel, ch1, ch3):
    super(Inception, self).__init__()
    self.branch1 = nn.Sequential(
        ConvBlock(in_channel, ch1, kernel_size = 1,stride=1, padding=0)
    )
    
    self.branch2 = nn.Sequential(
        ConvBlock(in_channel, ch3, kernel_size = 3,stride=1, padding=0)
    )
    
def forward(self, x):
    branch1 = self.branch1(x)
    branch2 = self.branch2(x)
    return torch.cat([branch1, branch2], 1) *(error here)*
```

Comment: As an update here, I already found the solution.  You have to compute the correct padding value.  Since this convolution block has stride of 1, padding is just (kernel_size-1)/2.  If I'm not mistaken, this is equivalent to padding ='same' in keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match your kernel size and padding.

For `kernel_size=1` no padding is needed, but for `kernel_size=3` you need padding to be 1:

```py
self.branch2 = nn.Sequential(
        ConvBlock(in_channel, ch3, kernel_size=3,stride=1, padding=1)
    )
```

See [this nice tutorial](https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-Part-2/) for more details.

Comment: Worked fine, so far. Thank you